# why Intent.ACTION_SEND dialog has second delay?

Tags: android, share-intent

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
progressDialog.setMessage("Waitting...");
progressDialog.show();
//sharing implementation
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
// what type of data needs to be send by sharing
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
// package names
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
// list package
List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(sharingIntent, 0);
List<ResolveInfo> newActivityList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Above is my code. The problem is the `ProgressDialog` has second delay show. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Progress dialogs only display if the following code has finished.

Comment: what is the following code ?

Comment: You accuse both dialogs of having a delay. Now which is it? You could have corrected your post meanwhile.